# Nonvulgar synonym for "smartass"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, tone

I just read a question here at ELU where a certain user, I'll call him A, disagreed with the premise in the question.  He wrote a comment to disagree with the premise, and wrote that actually, such-and-so grammar thing is not necessarily disallowed.  OP requested an example that would be kosher.  A gave a *smartass* response, telling OP to study the difference between certain fields of study.

I need an alternative way of expressing the idea of the smartass response, that's not vulgar.  It doesn't have to be a single word and it's okay to rewrite the sentence.

Comment: Is *smart aleck* polite enough? Or do you want wiseacre?  Or something else?

Comment: @Jim - Smart aleck  and wiseacre are pretty good but I'm hoping for something stronger.

Comment: Stronger but polite??

Comment: @Jim - good point, thank you, I've edited the question and title to say "nonvulgar" instead of polite.

Comment: ... gave an ***infuriating non-answer***...

Comment: @Jim - Thanks, that's progress, but we're not there yet.  I was definitely irritated, but not infuriated.  I somehow need to get A's attitude conveyed.  (The smartass attitude.)

Comment: An ***derogatory non-answer***....  An Irritating derogatory non-answer...

Comment: I'm unsure about derogatory.  Maybe.  Do you want to write an answer?

Comment: disparaging non-answer...

Comment: Maybe disrespectful non-answer.

Comment: actually ,  you tug more chains by being patronizing.  "How clever of you" ?

Comment: @Tom22 - There you go, *patronizing non-answer*

Comment: Actually I know the question you’re talking about, and I think it was more of a ***flippant remark.***

Comment: @Jim - You're welcome to your opinion; I have mine, which I don't intend to express on that page, directly to A.

Comment: @Tom22 I wrote a flag using the word "smartass" but I would like to be able to express that thought with a cleaner word.

Comment: ***Snide***?  I don't know the whole context though.

Comment: Maybe you got the word / phrase you were looking for, but if you would consider a frankly descriptive combination of adjectives, may I suggest 'unhelpful and condescending' --
*The response was unhelpful and condescending.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Know-it-all, wise-guy, wiseacre or smarty-pants are synonyms for smartass that do not have swearwords in them.

A know-it-all or a wise-guy, usually used in a sarcastic tone, means that a person acts as if he is a professional in the matter that he is talking about while he's clearly not. Examples:

> Ooh, look at Mr. Know-it-all! You know everything, don't you?
>
> Hey, Mr Wise-guy, what do you think about this evidence that proves you dead-wrong?

Wiseacre or smarty-pants are usually used for people who are new to the issues but they're talking as if their input is the most important one in the room. They can usually be interchanged with the others.

In your case I'd use know-it-all, since it would look better on an exchange site (seems more professional than others even though it should be avoided in professional situations):

> He gave a know-it-all response, telling OP to study the difference between certain fields of study.

Comment: I think I'm going to go with **smarty-pants** as the clean equivalent for smartass.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for something "kosher" - you can try

> **Chutzpadik** - not showing due respect; impudent; impertinent; brazen ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/chutzpadik))

It comes from yiddish and seems to embody what you're looking for

Comment: Thank you.  I know *chutzpah* but I didn't know *chutzpadik*.  Can you give me a link to hear the pronunciation, or can you record it by itself and in a sentence?

Answer (score 3):

There is the expression [*Clever Clogs*](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=clever+clogs&t=crmtb01).

A person who is ostentatiously and annoyingly knowledgeable.

This was widely used in my childhood but I haven't heard it so often nowadays.

Comment: My parents used that when we were growing up, to stop us getting too big for our boots. Since they grew up in a Lancashire mill town where clogs were a part of life, I assumed it was a regionalism. Is/was it more widely used?

Comment: Note that this is a [BrE thing](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/clever-dick-clogs). As an American, I have never heard this before.

Comment: @Laurel As an American, I have -- from British friends.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatives:

A provided an inappropriately abrasive and arrogant response.

Or,

A responded with an obnoxiously condescending retort which added little to finding an appropriate resolution to the OP's original question.

Do you want any more examples? Also, who is the audience to which the comment is to be directed?